# XSD and WSDL in different directories

Tags: maven, wsdl, wsimport, java-ws

At my work used jaxws-maven-plugin for code generation.
I have two projects are "common" and'' client ". Structure roughly as follows:

```
app/
  common/
    resource/
      some.xsd
  client/
    resource/
      some.wsdl
```

How can I generate classes from wsdl in the project "client", using the xsd from the project "common"?

pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${project.parent.basedir}/common/resource/some.xsd</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>/resource/some.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should stick to the maven conventions, use `src/main/resources/` directories for resources.

After doing that then you can use the [`maven-dependency-plugin:unpack-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-project-dependencies.html) to unpack the `common` jar file to access the `some.xsd`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow.Q13155047</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>client</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <schema.location>${project.build.directory}/schemas</schema.location>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow.Q13155047</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**/*.xsd</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${schema.location}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <bindingDirectory>${schema.location}</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <bindingFile>some.xsd</bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                            <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>some.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The [`jaxws-maven-plugin`](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) is bound to the `generate-sources` phase so adding the `maven-dependency-plugin` before the `jaxws-maven-plugin` and to the same phase makes sure that it unpacks everything before applying the `wsimport` goal.

Make sure that `<bindingDirectory/>` and `<wsdlDirectory/>` are correct.

---

This is how you should do it if you have the `*.xsd` files in another project. **Never** access other projects with relative paths. Each project should only access other resources using the dependency mechanism.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just trying to get through all the relative paths.

Comment: As per this link - the default location used by maven wsimport plugin is src/wsdl. I infer that .wsdl should not be kept in src/main/resources. 
https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html

Comment: How do you reference the XSDs in the WSDL when you are unpacking to the ${schema.location} directory? How does the WSDL know where to find the XSDs?