# Referencing/using files in an external maven project

Tags: java, maven

So I have 2 projects A and B, A having a dependency on B in pom.xml . I have a file in A which wants to use a resource in B called C.wsdl. I use the following way to refer it:

```
 wsdlLocation="classpath:/wsdl/C/C.wsdl"
```

I installed B then installed A using maven. I open A's target folder and find A.zip. I extract A.zip and find a lib folder containing B's jar file. I extract the jar which has a folder C containing C.wsdl.

But I get the following error

**Can't find wsdl at classpath:/wsdl/QuerySubscriberInfoService/QuerySubscriberInfoService?wsdl**

Also that works if the file is in A itself.

Any idea where Im going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly, the author of this topic is having similiar problems, please check

[XSD and WSDL in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155047/xsd-and-wsdl-in-different-directories)

If this is possible for you to initialize wsdlLocation dynamically, 
you can use

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("wsdl/C/C.wsdl")
```

**Please note** that it is only possible to extract content of such files (which are packaged inside of dependant jar) only via streams, i.e

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("wsdl/C/C.wsdl")
```